# Alternative to in_array or multiple OR in if-statement

Tags: php, optimization, if-statement

So, as the title says... any alternative to:

```
$valid_times = array('ever', 'today', 'week', 'month');
if (($this->_time == 'ever') OR ($this->_time == 'day'))
```

OR

```
if (in_array($this->_time, $valid_times))
```

??

Note: I know the mentioned above works, but I'm just looking for new things to learn and experiment with

### UPDATE

Thanks for the info, but I didn't mentioned `switch()` as an alternative because it's not the case for my code. It has to be an if-statement, and I was wondering if exists something like:

```
if($this->_time == (('ever') OR ('day') OR ('month')))
```

What do you think? That would be a shorter way of the first if mentioned above

Comment: Whether the second is an alternative to the first depends on the content of `$valid_times`.

Comment: This would all depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Given the updated question, I've rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about ?

```
$a1 = array("one","two","three");
$found = "two";
$notFound = "four";

if (count(array_diff($a1,array($found))) != count($a1))
/* Found */
```

Either you can use

```
$found = array("one","three");

if (count(array_diff($a1,$found)) != count($a1));
/* Either one OR three */
```

http://codepad.org/FvXueJkE

Comment: interesting method, you just gave me an idea to fix something else +1

Comment: I was curious about this question too, also this solution looks interessting.. but now I am curious is with gives any advantages, even if it's 0.0001seconds faster execution or something.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Removed original answer since you've now specified you don't want to use `switch`.

In your updated question, you asked if something like this is possible:

```
if($this->_time == (('ever') OR ('day') OR ('month')))
```

The direct answer is 'no, not in PHP'. The closest you'll get is `in_array()`, with the array values in place in the same line of code:

```
if(in_array($this->_time, array('ever','day','month'))
```

PHP 5.4 has an update allows for shorter array syntax, which means you can drop the word `array`, which makes it slightly more readable:

```
if(in_array($this->_time, ['ever','day','month'])
```

But it is still an `in_array()` call. You can't get around that.

Answer (score 2):

The only alternative I can think to accomplish this would be using regex.

```
$valid_times = array('ever','day','week','hour');

if(preg_match('/' . implode('|', $valid_times) . '/i', $this->_time)){
    // match found
} else {
    // match not found
}
```

Comment: Well, well.. it works and answers the question, but I hoped to find something more effective, rather than a Regex which makes it actually less effective :P (at least I assume that it is) Maybe this solution can be helpful in some other cases

Answer (score 1):

Sometime like this for in_array?

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 'test');
$myVar = 2;

function my_in_array($val, $arr){
    foreach($arr as $arrVal){
        if($arrVal == $val){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if(my_in_array($myVar, $arr)){
    echo 'Found!';
}
```

Comment: that's hardly an alternative; that's just re-writing the existing built-in function.

Comment: @SDC He said he's just looking to experiment. Could be a HW assignment to write your own version of PHP functions for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

Convoluted, but it is an alternative

```
$input = 'day';
$validValues = array('ever','day');
$result = array_reduce($validValues,
                       function($retVal,$testValue) use($input) {
                           return $retVal || ($testValue == $input);
                       },
                       FALSE
                      );
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the switch statement.

```
switch ($this->_time) {
  case 'ever':
  case 'day':
    //code
    break;
  default:
    //something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of science, it turns out you can use `yield` in a ternary operator, so you could put some complex evaluations in a anonymous generator, and have it yield on the first one that evaluates to true, without needing to evaluate them all:

```
$time = 'today';
if( (function()use($time){
    $time == 'ever' ? yield true:null;
    $time == 'today' ? yield true:null;
    $time == 't'.'o'.'d'.'a'.'y' ? yield true:null;
})()->current() ){
    echo 'valid';
}
```

In this case it will echo `'valid'` without ever evaluating the concatenation.